# How to get tweets for the REST API like if it was from the Stream API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, twitter, stream

I'm currently building a Twitter app and I'm facing a problem since two months for a specific function.

This is what I wish to do: display the tweets from the user's Twitter lists and refresh them with new tweets. Twitter offers stream API to get new tweets instantly. However, to get the list's tweets, the Twitter API allows me only to get them through a REST API and not a stream API.

My idea is then to make regular REST API calls, compare the new tweets, and then to add each new tweet to the interface "like if it was a real stream".

For doing this, I've done the function below to compare an array of objects. I'm checking each tweet ID to compare them.Tests have been written and they all pass.

Unfortunately, my app behaves akwardly and keeps adding tweets even though they are no differences between the current and the incoming ones. 
So, perhaps the problem comes from somewhere else, but I think it is not the place here to submit pages of code for getting you to help me to fix my problem. (But if you are interested, I'm okay to share the code).

So here's my question: Am I doing things right, or do you see a better solution for what I want to do?

```js
/**
 * Return the difference between the current messages in the array and the incoming
 * @param  {Array} incoming Array of incoming tweets
 * @return {Array} current  Array of current tweets
 */
MessagesDisplay.prototype.compareCurrentListWithIncoming = function(incoming, current){
    // Return the elements not present in the array
    Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
        return this.filter(function(array) {
            var exist = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if(array.id_str === a[i].id_str){
                    exist = true;
                }
            };
            if(!exist){
                return array;
            }
        });
    };
    var messagesToAdd = []; 
    
    messagesToAdd = incoming.diff(current);

    return {
        messagesToAdd: messagesToAdd,
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with you code, the problem should be somewhere else, yes. However, which REST method are you using? [user timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)? You could use the parameter `since_id` to guarantee you're receiving only the new tweets. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm now trying with the since_id parameter. However, I'm a bit frustrated because it wasn't the way I wished. Like this, I still can't detect the tweets which are deleted.